# trouble bridging tap0 and tap1

Tags: networking, ethernet, bridge, tap, ifconfig

I have a GNS3 router that is connected to `tap1` in my host. On the other hand, I have an user application connected to `tap0` running locally in my host.  I can ping both the router and my application.  I want my application to talk with the router, so I thought of adding a bridge between `tap0` and `tap1`, like this (using OS X 10.10):

```
ifconfig bridge1 create addm tap0 addm tap1 up
```

(see my `ifconfig` output [here](https://gist.github.com/nojb/c977b966acf769a42f63)).

`Wireshark` shows that packets sent by my router reach `bridge1`, however they never reach `tap0`. I have been trying to solve this for two days now and I am completely lost.

Comment: This question might be better off on ServerFault.

Comment: ...or even on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). Creating and managing bridge network information is highly OS-specific and non -portable and for the purposes of this question, you need a MacOS expert specifically.

Comment: **[Reposted on Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/642504/trouble-bridging-tap0-and-tap1)**. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) — and @JohnWHSmith please do not recommend posting on multiple sites. Nicolás, your question is on-topic here, and I think it's also on-topic on [sf], but pick one and delete the other, before they get answered on both sites.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bridge is working[1], you have the two devices connected together at layer two (MAC layer); are both sides on the same layer three (IP) network? Can you describe how "the user application [is] connected to tap0"? (I'm assuming the router in GNS3 is attached to tap1 via a "cloud".)

@Celada, Mac OS X networking is the same as FreeBSD, on which Darwin (the OSS core of Mac OS X) is based; see http://blog.up-link.ro/freebsd-how-to-create-a-network-bridge/ for a simple howto on FreeBSD bridging.

[1] You should see the MAC addr's learned on the bridge by the command output from 'ifconfig bridge0 addr' - by your Gist, you should see '5e:70:93:9c:ae:ce' and 'fe:e4:46:22:2f:cc'